# Enable Submit/Cancel button through WPF Command pattern

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

My View contains the following 2 buttons:

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Button Content="Start" Width="100" Height="30" Margin="20" Command="{Binding OkCommand}"/>
        <Button Content="Cancel" Width="100" Height="30" Margin="20" Command="{Binding CancelCommand}"/>
 </StackPanel>
```

In my VM - I have the command interception setup.

```
class StockViewModel
{
    #region Properties
    public ICommand OkCommand { get; set; }
    public ICommand CancelCommand { get; set; }
    #endregion

#region Constructor
    public StockViewModel()
    {
        OkCommand = new myCommand(myOkExecute, myCanOkExecute);
        CancelCommand = new myCommand(myCancelExecute, myCanCancelExecute);
    }
    #endregion

    private void myOkExecute (object parameter)
    {
       ......
    }

    private bool myCanOkExecute(object parameter)
    {
       ........
    }

    private bool myCanCancelExecute(object parameter)
    {
      .......
    }

    private myCanCancelExecute(object parameter)
    {
     ............
    }
    #endregion


   public class myCommand : ICommand
   {

   }
```

Question: I want the behavior of the buttons to be opp - meaning when one is clicked (Submit) the other should by disabled and vice versa. when the form loads for the first time - Submit btn is enabled by default.

I tried multiple ways - but cant seem to get this working.

I am doing plain MVVM code here - with no prism/event aggregator concepts.

Can people recommend (with a code smaple) how is such a command bheavior generally handled.

Comment: Why can't your command raise the ICommand.CanExecuteChanged event?

Comment: See the updated code - it has all the events - just cant seem to figure how to access the btnState there and set them to true or false

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    private bool IsOkToExecute
    {
        get { return _isOkToExecute; }
        set
        {
            _isOkToExecute = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("IsOkToExecute");
        }
    }

     private void myOkExecute (object parameter)
     {
        IsOkToExecute = false;
     }

    private void myCancelExecute(object parameter)
     {
         IsOkToExecute = true;
     }

private bool myCanOkExecute(object parameter)
{
    return IsOkToExecute;
}

private bool myCanCancelExecute(object parameter)
{
    return !IsOkToExecute;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Denis - this worked like a charm !!! I have always been practicing with having button behavior tied to a textbox (whether a value has been entered or not) and hence this ended up being a tough one for me. Though once on implementing this solution - makes perfect sense.

Thanks once again